# Get every Button with a certain tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the color of all the buttons of a "pagination" when I click on one of them.
So I tagged these buttons `PageButton`

Usually, I use `FindGameObjectsWithTag` to get a collection of elements with a certain tag. But even by casting it as `Button` It doesn't work/show an error and I don't find anything else than `FindGameObjectsWithTag` in the suggestion nor in the doc

```
private Button[] buttons;

void Start()
{
    //this show me an error telling me I can't convert form UI to gameobject
    buttons = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PageButton") as Button;

    foreach(Button button in buttons)
    {
        //my code to change every buttons color will go here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply cast `GameObject` to `Button`. You need to use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)!

You could either do it straight forward and use

```
var objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PageButton");
buttons = new Button[objs.Length];
for(var i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
{
    buttons[i] = objs[i].GetComponent<Button>();
}
```

or use [Linq `Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) and do

```
using System.Linq;

...

buttons = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PageButton").Select(obj => obj.GetComponent<Button>()).ToArray();
```

---

Alternatively you could also go the other way round and find all `Button`s in the scene using [`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) and then filter by the tag like e.g.

```
var allButtons = FindObjectsOfType<Button>();
var taggedButtons = new List<Button>();
foreach(var button in allButtons)
{
    if(button.CompareTag("PageButton"))
    {
       taggedButtons.Add(button);
    }
}
buttons = taggedbuttons.ToArray();
```

again you could use [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) to shorten this

```
buttons = FindObjectsOfType<Button>().Where(button => button.CompareTag("PageButton")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ok, didn't knew about Linq, it's awesome actually. But in my declaration of the variable, should I keep Button type? `private Button buttons;`

Comment: @Richard yes/no .. you still want an **array** `private Button[] buttons`

Comment: if inside the `Start` method is the only place where you do something with them you don't need a field at all actually ;) in that case remove the field and just put a `var` in front of `buttons` ;)

Comment: No no I'm changing the color in a custom function aswell ^^. I'm trying this out and let you know fast

Comment: Ok it works perfectly. I chosed the first alternative